# What effect does optimsing for cluster size have in appfabric

Tags: appfabric

We have an appfabric cache where "small 1-5" is selected as the cluster size.

We are now adding extra machines, which will bring the number of machines over 5.

Should we recreate the cluster to select the correct size? Or does it not make that much of a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some detail [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/dublin/thread/a2a296e1-5e21-4825-9b29-7aec7f26b97c) on what effect setting the cluster size has internally to AppFabric. I think the effect of this in practice will be that as your cluster grows in size, accessing cached data may become less efficient/performant.

I've not looked into this too closely - the clusters I've used for playing around with and getting a feel for AppFabric have only ever had a couple of servers in them - so I can't say how much of an effect this might have on your code. You'd have to try it and see what the impact is like (and then come back here and tell us so we preserve the knowledge!). If the impact is small, then you may be able to live with it, if not then you'll need to look at recreating the cluster.

Comment: Thanks, we ended up rebuilding the cluster. One interesting thing was that my selecting medium the first 3 servers were automatically configured to be lead servers.

Comment: @Shiraz That *is* interesting and definitely worth knowing. I wonder how many lead servers you get for a large cluster...